# PHP invalid argument in foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a main php file that I am including in my php file that I am calling the functions from.

My main file has this function

```
function GetComments()
{
global $server;
global $info;
global $dbhandle;

$query = "SELECT GbId, fname, lname, comment FROM Guestbook";

$result = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, $query);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$array[$row['GbId']] = array(
'f' => trim($row['fname']),
'l' => trim($row['lname']),
'c' => trim($row['comment']));
}

return $array;
}
```

and my webpage document has this code

```
<?php
$array = GetComments();

foreach($array as $key => $info)
{
echo $info['f']." ".$info['l']." said "."&quot;".$info['c']."&quot;"."<br /><br />";
}

Close();
?>
```

This code works fine when the foreach loop is in the main file, but I get a warning after all the data is printed out when it is in the webpage file.  I'm not too concerned about it as it still works, but I would like to either get rid of it, fix it, or at least know why it is happening.

Thanks

Comment: what warning is shown?

Comment: You didn't say which exact error message you get.

Comment: The exact error is Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurs because foreach expects array as input, but provided variable is not array at some piont.

Solution : If it is not array, make it a null array.

Try adding this line `if(!is_array($array)){ $array = array(); }` after `$array = GetComments();`

```
$array = GetComments();
if(!is_array($array)){ $array = array(); }
```

EDIT : Declare the array before while loop in your function

```
$array     = array();
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$array[$row['GbId']] = array(
'f' => trim($row['fname']),
'l' => trim($row['lname']),
'c' => trim($row['comment']));
}

return $array;
```

Comment: Could you explain how it wouldn't be an array?  I'm just confused because I thought it was an array.

Comment: One case is when you don't have any records in your database

Comment: One more thing I forgot to tell you, declare the array before while loop in your function. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
foreach( (array) $array as $key => $info)
```